# MS Access ODBC Connection with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed Oracle SQL Developer and I have created an MS access database called LD.accdb. I want to connect to my database with the Oracle SQL Developer. My OS is WIn 7 and I run MS Access 2010. I follow the steps as presented in the following link:

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/ms-access-queries-oracle-sql-developer-12-tool

but when I test my connection from the SQL Developer (see after completing fig.13 in the link above) and test my connection, it fails with the following error message:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

So I go to the ODBC Data Source Administrator (Control Panel-->Administrative Tools) and I have tried some things but I have not been successful making my connection successful. Can you help me on that?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer v4.0.3 is the version that supports MS Access database connections.

The JDBC/ODBC Bridge was deprecated in JAVA JRE v1.8.  As of version SQL Developer 4.1 and above required the JAVA JRE v1.8.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is clear. I use SQL developer v4.0.2.15 so I will update it accordingly.

Comment: Please see my other thread at "Making a connection to an Access Database with SQL Developer v4.0.3 and the JDBC/ODBC Bridge" in Stackoverflow.  I had the same issue as well as some others.  My answer is more complete in addition to my comments above.